# How to correctly format text alignment for the footer section of a webpage with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, formatting, footer

I am trying to format the footer section of a webpage so that the address and its corresponding info is parallel with the contact information. Basically, all the address info will be on the left and the contact info is on the right and ideally aligned uniformly. I've tried changing some parameters and adding parameters in an attempt to correct the formatting.

This is the output I am getting.

[image]

Any suggestion on how to correct this?
Here is the code for context.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div class="footer-row">
<div class="footer-left">
    <h1>Address</h1>
    <p><strong>Name of place</strong><br>
       <em>at the intersection of such and such</em><br>
       111 address st <br>
       City Name, State 12345 <br>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="footer-right"></div>
    <h1>Contact</h1>
    <p>
       111-222-3333 <br>
       email@email.com<br>
    </p>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.footer-row{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.footer-left,.footer-right{
    flex-basis: 45%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
.footer-right{
    text-align: right;
}

.footer-row h1{
    margin: 10px 0; 
}

.footer-row p{
    line-height: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `flex-direction: column`;
and
remove div closing tag at

```
<div class="footer-right"></div>
```

```css
.footer-row{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    
    flex-direction: row;
}
.footer-left,.footer-right{
    flex-basis: 45%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
.footer-right{
    text-align: right;
}

.footer-row h1{
    margin: 10px 0; 
}

.footer-row p{
    line-height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-row">
  <div class="footer-left">
      <h1>Address</h1>
      <p><strong>Name of place</strong><br>
         <em>at the intersection of such and such</em><br>
         111 address st <br>
         City Name, State 12345 <br>
      </p>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-right">
      <h1>Contact</h1>
      <p>
         111-222-3333 <br>
         email@email.com<br>
      </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The main issue was that extra tag. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display-grid` css. When you learn to use, you never use other ways ;)

You can use just like that:

```
.footer-row {
  display: inline-grid;
  width: 100%;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

See the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3v7qh2cg/2/)

Comment: Nice! I will try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Your css is absolutely correct, and no rule needs to be added. The problem was html structure. It's enough to remove the closing `</div>` tag after `<div class = "footer-right">` - that's the only problem.

I added a 515px `media query` for you, which aligns the content.

```css
.footer-row{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.footer-left,.footer-right{
    flex-basis: 45%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
.footer-right{
    text-align: right;
}

.footer-row h1{
    margin: 10px 0; 
}

.footer-row p{
    line-height: 25px;
}

@media(max-width: 515px){
    .footer-row{
      justify-content: center;
  }
    .footer-right{
    text-align: left;
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<div class="footer-row">
  <div class="footer-left">
      <h1>Address</h1>
      <p><strong>Name of place</strong><br>
         <em>at the intersection of such and such</em><br>
         111 address st <br>
         City Name, State 12345 <br>
      </p>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-right">
      <h1>Contact</h1>
      <p>
         111-222-3333 <br>
         email@email.com<br>
      </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very helpful in making sure the webpage formats properly on mobile!

Answer (score 0):

So the first thing you should do is drop the  at the end of your "footer-right" class and make sure to wrap the elements beneath it correctly. Second, you only need this bit of code in CSS to give you a pretty responsive footer like you're looking for.

```css
.footer-row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div class="footer-row">
<div class="footer-left">
    <h1>Address</h1>
    <p><strong>Name of place</strong><br>
       <em>at the intersection of such and such</em><br>
       111 address st <br>
       City Name, State 12345 <br>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="footer-right">
    <h1>Contact</h1>
    
    <p>
       111-222-3333 <br>
       email@email.com<br>
    </p>
    </div>
  </div>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, however omitting "margin: 0 auto" causes the formatting to shift off center.